# Quantum Circuit evaluation Qiskit vs. AWS Braket SDK

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, programming, amazon-braket

I am examining a simple circuit using both Qiskit and the AWS Braket SDK (Python).  The circuit is very simple.

```
T  : |0|1|
          
q0 : -C-C-
      | | 
q1 : -Z-|-
        | 
q2 : ---Z-
```

I trying to find the equivalent unitary operator for this circuit.  I get different answers from Qiskit and AWS Braket SDK and I don't know why.

Here is my Qiskit code:

```
from qiskit import *
qr = QuantumRegister(3, 'q')
cr = ClassicalRegister(0, 'c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
circuit.cz(qr[0], qr[1])
circuit.cz(qr[0], qr[2])

simulator = Aer.get_backend('unitary_simulator')
result = execute(circuit, backend = simulator).result() 
matprint(result.get_unitary().data)

def matprint(mat, fmt="g"):
    col_maxes = [max([len(("{:"+fmt+"}").format(x)) for x in col]) for col in mat.T]
    for x in mat:
        for i, y in enumerate(x):
            print(("{:"+str(col_maxes[i])+fmt+"}").format(y), end="  ")
        print("")
```

The Qiskit result is:

```
 1+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j  
 0+0j   1+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j  
 0+0j   0+0j   1+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j  
-0+0j  -0+0j  -0+0j  -1+0j  -0+0j  -0+0j  -0+0j  -0+0j  
 0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   1+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j  
-0+0j  -0+0j  -0+0j  -0+0j  -0+0j  -1+0j  -0+0j  -0+0j  
 0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   0+0j   1+0j   0+0j  
 0-0j   0-0j   0-0j   0-0j   0-0j   0-0j   0-0j   1-0j
```

This is what I expected from my hand-calculations.  However, when using AWS Braket SDK I get something different.  The Braket code:

```
from braket.circuits import Circuit
db=Circuit().cz(0,1).cz(0,2)
print(db.to_unitary())
```

The result is:

```
[[ 1.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  1.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  1.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  1.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  1.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j -1.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j -1.+0.j  0.+0.j]
 [ 0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  0.+0.j  1.+0.j]]
```

I believe the Qiskit answer is correct because it is consistent with "I kron CZ" for the first operation.  If I do "CZ kron I" for the first operation I get the Braket answer.

I am new to quantum computing and would find an explanation valuable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the difference is that Qiskit and Braket use different endianness for their qubits; Qiskit is little endian:
$$
| q_{n - 1} \ldots q_2 q_1 q_0 \rangle
$$
while Braket is big-endian:
$$
| q_0 q_1 q_2 \ldots q_{n - 1} \rangle
$$
You can show this by reversing the endianness of the Qiskit unitary:

```python
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
Operator(circuit).reverse_qargs().to_matrix()
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will read up on this.  I am wondering if this difference makes it's way into the assembly.  Maybe simulators/hardware are one or the other?  I will find out.

Comment: Endianness doesn't have an impact on the way the program is run; you can easily reverse endianness by reversing the qubits before running the program. This is just a convention for result readout.